# C++ QT Adaptive Layout

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I am trying to create multiple widgets stacked depending on the size of the window. If the window is wide enough to insert one block from vertical layout down, then do it (see image).

[image]

[image]

And also if the window is too small, you can scroll through widgets.
Here is code I tried:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QVBoxLayout *v_layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    QHBoxLayout *h_layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    QWidget *actualLayout = new QWidget();

    int a = 50;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        QWidget *new_widget = new QWidget();
        new_widget->setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: red }");
        new_widget->setFixedSize(a, a);

        v_layout->addWidget(new_widget);
    }
    actualLayout->setLayout(v_layout);
    setCentralWidget(actualLayout);
}
```

Comment: There is no layout (I know of) which does this automatically. However, you may write your custom layouter. There is an introduction for this in the Qt doc.: [How to Write A Custom Layout Manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#how-to-write-a-custom-layout-manager) It even mentions the [Flow Layout Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) which looks like a really good start for what you intend to achieve (IMHO).